# Docker run to kubernetes yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

I have a docker run command like below:
 `docker run -it -p 5901:5901 -p 6901:6901 --user 1000 --privileged check-user bash` 
I would like to cover that command to Kubernetes yaml to create the pod.
Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `check-user` is name of the docker image

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: check-user
  name: check-user
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - bash
    image: check-user
    name: check-user
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5901
    - containerPort: 6901
    tty: true
    stdin: true
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 1000
      privileged: true
  restartPolicy: Never
```