# Docker run command options in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-run

I am starting my docker container using following command
docker run -it -d -p 80001:8000.
Now i want to use use docker container in kubernetes using deployment. How to setup container spec secion of deployment for above mentioned arugment -it and -d. both are require.So first allocate stdin and tty to pod and then keep it running into detach mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `-it -d`. Kubernetes `deployment` will wake-up the pod in detached mode. Interactive mode (-i) has no sense because it runs in detached mode, and -t (allowcate pseudo tty) also don't needed. There is thread in about dealing with tty in deployments here https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/hczzi2/when_dealing_with_deployments_what_does_tty_true/

If you need later access to this pod you can use `kubectl exec -ti <podname> -- bash`.

Remember that your pod should run in background some kind of service or at least an sleep loop.

Here more information on how to do this kind of loop [How can I keep a container running on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-a-container-running-on-kubernetes)

Update:

If you want to run a pod in Kubernetes with -ti you can do:

`kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never --port=8001`

after exit remember to delete it with `kubectl delete pod busybox`

If you want forward ports you can do:

`kubectl port-forward busybox 8001:8001` and go to localhost:8001

Comment: @SiHa He is asking for run container in kubernetes with `-ti` nothing about port configuration in deployment. `How to setup container spec secion of deployment for above mentioned arugment -it and -d`

Comment: my docker container need -it at start. otherwise docker cmd command will exit.

Comment: @AkshayGopani No way to do this with kubernetes, kubernetes pod always run in detached mode.

Comment: @AkshayGopani checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-a-container-running-on-kubernetes

Comment: @TlmaK0 what about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55584280/docker-run-to-kubernetes-yaml . there tty and std

Comment: @AkshayGopani I'm not sure how tty:true and stdin:true will afect your pod in a deployment, but if you only want to run a pod you can do `kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never`

Comment: @AkshayGopani I have updated the answer with run it as a pod directly and not as a deployment

Comment: @TlmaK0 i want to  run pod from deployment.

Comment: @AkshayGopani so you need to execute a loop, if not the pod will stop, and then run `kubectl exec -ti pod-name -- bash` to access the pod running in the cluster

Comment: @AkshayGopani Provided answer has all you need to start with. Remember: kubernetes is not docker, here it works differently. Get familiar with [kubernetes documentation specifically about pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) and manifests. Also there are imperative or declarative ways to create resources - see [article about it](https://medium.com/payscale-tech/imperative-vs-declarative-a-kubernetes-tutorial-4be66c5d8914)

Comment: @AkshayGopani Also see [kubernetes api reference - pod.spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/#podspec-v1-core) and there are no `tty` or `std` fields. So as correctly TimaK0 mentioned those fields do not make any sense. I suggest reading official kubernetes documentation as a source of up-to-date information.